# How to get data from [object object] in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

In console i am getting data as [object Object].
console.log('data is: '+ (data));

```
data is:  [object Object]
```

When i am doing json stringify,
console.log('data is: '+ JSON.stringify(data)); 
I am getting data in this format:

```
{
"employee":
       { "name":"John", 
         "age":30, 
         "city":"New York" 
      }
}
```

I have 3 variable name , age and city.I want to get those values from this data in ts file.

```
name: any;
age: any;
city: any;
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmployeedetailsComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data, private dialog: MatDialog){
   this.name = data.name;
}
```

this.name = data.name; this is not working. How to get these values.Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be data.employee.name

Answer (score 1):

You need change to    `this.name = data.employee.name;`

```
 constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmployeedetailsComponent>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data, private dialog: MatDialog){
   this.name = data.employee.name;
}
```